# How to make a string non-appendable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this even possible?

```
function from_country_to_country(country_from, country_to) {
    // get the right zone prices
    var zone_price = zone_finder(country_to['zone']);
    $('#country_to_country').html(country_from['land']);
    $('#call').html(formatPrice(country_from[zone_price]) + ' kr/min');
    $('#recieve').html(formatPrice(country_from['receive_calls']) + ' kr/min');
    $('#send_sms').html(formatPrice(country_from['send_sms']) + ' kr/SMS');
    $('#recieve_sms').html(formatPrice(country_from['receive_sms']) + ' kr/SMS');
    $('#opening_fee').html(formatPrice(country_from['opening_fee']) + ' kr');
}

function within_the_country(country) {
    $('#from_within').html(country['land']);
    $('#from_domestic').html(formatPrice(country['domestic']) + ' kr/min');
    $('#from_RCF').html(formatPrice(country['receive_calls']) + ' kr/min');
    $('#from_send_sms').html(formatPrice(country['send_sms']) + ' kr/SMS');
    $('#from_recieve_sms').html(formatPrice(country['receive_sms']) + ' kr/SMS');
    $('#from_opening_fee').html(formatPrice(country['opening_fee']) + ' kr');
    $('#from_gprs_data').html(formatPrice(country['data_price'])+ ' kr/mb');
}

// Format prices from ex: turns 1 into 1,00
function formatPrice(n) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(n))) {
        n = parseFloat(n);
        n = Math.round(n * 100) / 100
        n = n.toFixed(2);
        return n;
    } else {
       // IF WE CAN MAKE "n" NON-APPENDABLE HERE 
        return n;
    }
}
```

If `n` is not a number I dont want `' kr/mb'` to be appended to the string. I know that I can check if it is a number and if not, dont append. But I have many different suffixes that I append onto the returning string of `formatPrice()`. So then I will need to check this everywhere. Is there a nice work around to this?

Comment: Strings are immutable so you can't change them, but there is no way to avoid someone taking your string and creating a new one based on it. But why not just pass the suffix to formatPrice as an optional parameter?

Comment: why not add `unit` as an argument to your `formatPrice` function and modify it to return a string? you can handle all the formatting logic (including what you're asking) there

Comment: @user3080953 I dont think i quit understand what you mean. Nvm, I understand works perfectly!

Comment: `function formatPrice(n, unit) { 
   if(!isNan ... ) {  
    return n + " " + unit; 
   } 
  else { 
    return n
} 
}`

Comment: @user3080953 Yes, thanks!

Comment: user3080953, just submit an answer with the changed code for formatPrice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust your `formatPrice` function to conditionally take in a unit:

```
function formatPrice(n, unit) {
  if(!isNan(...)) { 
    ... 
    return n + " " + unit; 
  } 
  else { 
    return n;  
  } 
} 

formatPrice(500, 'kr/mb');
```